# JMeter not able to show Chinese characters in view results tree

Tags: jmeter

I have set my OS system locale language as Chinese and set Charset as UTF-8 for the specific HTTP request. However Jmeter still not able to show Chinese characters in view results tree. Any leads? [image]

Comment: The issue was resolved by enabling the below functions in jmeter.properties
sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8
jsyntaxtextarea.font.family=Hack

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set [`file.encoding`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding) system property to UTF-8, add the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
file.encoding=UTF-8
```

and restart JMeter to pick the property up.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)